# Trouble accessing a text with XPath query

Tags: xpath

I have this html snippet

```
<div id="overview">
    <strong>some text</strong>
    <br/>
    some other text
    <strong>more text</strong>
    TEXT I NEED IS HERE
    <div id="sub">...</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the text I am looking for (shown in caps)?

I tried this, I get an error message saying not able to locate the element.

```
"//div[@id='overview']/strong[position()=2]/following-sibling"
```

I tried this, I get the div with id=sub, but not the text (correctly so)

```
"//div[@id='overview']/*[preceding-sibling::strong[position()=2]]"
```

Is there anyway to get the text, other than doing some string matching or regex with contents of overview div?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI `[position()=2]` can be (and generally is) abbreviated as `[2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`following-sibling` is the [*axis*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes), you still need to specify the actual node (in your example the XPath processor is searching for an element named `following-sibling`). You separate the axis from the node with `::`.

Try this:

```
//div[@id='overview']/strong[position()=2]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

This specifies the first text node after the second `strong` in the div.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want the text immediately preceding the `<div id="sub">` then you could try

```
//div[@id='sub']/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

That would give you everything between the `</strong>` and the opening `<div ...`, i.e. the upper case text plus its leading and trailing new lines and whitespace.